# How to install aps in Windroy?

Tags: android, windows, installation, windroy

I just started with [windroy](http://windroy.com/)

**How to install apps in Windroy?**

I can copy .apk files into `windroy_root\system\app`, but then I need to restart Windroy.

I checked web site and files in `windroy_root`, there is no real docs.
Also there is no any app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I used to install apps on Windroy

1. Download the Apk Installer and put it in windroy_root\system\app. I used this link http://www.appsapk.com/apk-installer/
2. Start Windroy
3. Go to Apps screen and you will see "Apk Installer" icon
4. Call it and navigate to where you put the .apk that you want to install
5. Double Click on .apf file

Answer (score 2):

This is for anyone using the newer version of windroy.
The new version v4.0.3 attempts to emulate android 4.0.3 but the trouble that i have
ran into is that not many apks will run properly. This being said you may have to make several attempts before you find an apk that will work, but the simple way of installing apks is to use a file manager because it gives you access to the file system for other tasks as well.

The file manager that i have choosen is Arc File Manager, Go File Master works as well but most pcs dont have an auto rotate feature which makes Go File Master annoying, Arc loads great plus it loads in landscape mode for easier use. I hope this helps
you if your running 4.0.3 or decide to use it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is download any launcher from a trusted site and place it in "windroy_root\system\app". Then place the apps you want to install in "windroy_root\mnt\sdcard\" and execute Windroy.

After booting you can select the launcher you just placed in "windroy_root\system\app".

Comment: Write only the answer of the question in the future !

Answer (score 1):

Download apk files and paste to **windroy_root\data\app**
Then restart windroy .

Answer (score 1):

I spent lot of time trying to figure how to run an app in Windroy. So here are the detailed steps to install apps on Windroy and run them. You can download Windroy from http://www.windroye.com/index_eng.html and install it.

```
1. After installing Windroy verify that it runs without error. 
2. In Windroy open a browser and download the Apk Installer from http://www.appsapk.com/apk-installer/ and install it once it gets downloaded 
3. Lets assume you have installed Windroy in 'C:\BaseInstall' folder.
4. Now open Windows Explorer, copy the apk of the app you want to install and paste it to 'C:\BaseInstall\Windroy\windroy_root\data\app' folder 
5. Now start Windroy and go to installed apps and you will see the 'app' you have copied installed in Windroy.
```